# mysql combine multiple tables in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables that a are structured like this. How can i query for the names. Usually i could query for the name with `name LIKE '%...%'`but i also want to include it when the movie name from `movies` matches. Can I also implement so that it ignores every result witht the same movie_id so it only finds one item for each movie?

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movies
(
    `id`         int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `movie_name` text NOT NULL
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movie_details
(
    `id`           int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `movie_id`     int       NOT NULL,
    `type`         int       NOT NULL,
    `start`        int       NOT NULL,
    `end`          int       NOT NULL,
    `name`         text      NOT NULL,
    `description`  text      NULL,
    `trailer`      text      NULL,
    `category`     text      NULL,
    `tags`         text      NULL,
    `studio`       text      NULL,
    `release_date` TIMESTAMP NULL
);
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Please provide data examples and what you have tried with results.    https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT DISTINCT md.name 
FROM movie_details md
LEFT JOIN movies m ON md.movie_id = m.id
WHERE md.name LIKE '%...%' OR m.movie_name LIKE '%...%'
```